# Toolbox fica com todos os itens desabilitados

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Tinha uma versão express do visual studio 2015. Desinstalei e instalei o visual studio professional 2013. Ao criar uma aplicação asp.net/web forms, os itens da minha toolbox ficam desabilitados. Já tentei:

- dar um reset toolbox
- Relacionar o item
- reiniciar o VS
- ir no diretório:
  C:\Users\Leonardo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0 e apagar
  todos os arquivos com extensão TDB.

e nada resolveu o problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Detalhe: Anteriormente, em aplicações windows form, tudo funcionava normal. Ao tentar criar uma aplicação asp.net/web forms, o erro ocorreu, e depois disso, nem a aplicação windows form esta com os componentes habilitados.

Detalhe 2: Em aplicações windows forms, ao clicar com o direito na opção toolbar e desmarcar a opção **show all** os itens voltaram a ficar habilitados. Já em um projeto web forms do asp.net, ao desmarcar a opção **show all** é apenas exibida esta mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu  vou ter que perguntar. Já tentou reiniciar? O computador? O VS? Tem alguma aplicação rodando? Você tá usando alguma biblioteca de gráficos?

Comment: já tentei reiniciar tanto o computador quanto o VS, não tenho nenhuma aplicação rodando e não estou utilizando nenhuma biblioteca gráfica. Seria recomendável desinstalar todo o visual studio, fazer uma limpeza completa de todas as versões dos registros de windows e instalar novamente?

Comment: Calma, moço! Vamos procurar uma solução.  Meu VS tá atualizando, então vai demorar um pouco, mas não mexe em registro algum, por favor.

Comment: Eu descobri por que, bruh! É por que você t´vendo no modo Web. Tenta abrir uma página .aspx e você vai ver que eles voltam.

Comment: eu cliquei em redefinir e tudo voltou ao normal[barra de ferramentas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNqKu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olha só!

No modo Web, somente, estão todos desabilitados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu abrir uma página .ASPX (onde eu posso trabalhar com código também), as ferramentas voltam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]